# php echo form inside div "wp"

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having a problem with my php code, when I try to echo a form inside a php I see it outside of div.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<div class="loginformheader" style="margin-top: 0;">
                <div id="reg-login"><a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'">خروج</a></div></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="loginformheader">'.header_login_form().'<div id="reg-login"><a href="'.site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register').'">تسجيل</a><span>|</span><a style="cursor: pointer;" id="logina">دخول</a><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></div></div>';
}
?>
```

The output

```
            <p class="login-username">
                <label for="user_login"></label>
                <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="اسم المستخدم">
            </p>
            <p class="login-password">
                <label for="user_pass"></label>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" placeholder="كلمة المرور">
            </p>

            <p class="login-remember"><label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"> تذكرني</label></p>
            <p class="login-submit">
                <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="تسجيل الدخول">
                <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/2014/10/30/links-post-2/">
            </p>

        </form><div class="loginformheader"><div id="reg-login"><a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-login.php?action=register">تسجيل</a><span>|</span><a style="cursor: pointer;" id="logina">دخول</a><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></div></div>                <hgroup class="site-branding">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/" rel="home"><img class="site-logo" src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/themes/merwaa/img/logo.svg"></a>
```

Maybe my English not very good, sorry me for that.
Can you help me?

Comment: Show source that PHP generates

Comment: This sounds like a CSS issue rather than a php issue.  It would be easier to address if we could see the page.

Comment: This code seems to be valid for me, i've just do not understand. Why do you create the `$loginformheader`, and then `echo` it? Why do not `echo` just that string? The problem will somewhere else, around your code.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I'm beginner in php, I just tried to solve it with this stupid method

Comment: @CaseyRule It's on local server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your `header_login_form()` function.  It almost certainly `echo`s the form, rather than returning it as a string.  If that's the case, it'll be `echo`ed when it's evaluated, which will be before the string it's in can be evaluated.  Try this instead:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<div class="loginformheader" style="margin-top: 0;">
                <div id="reg-login"><a href="'. wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ).'">خروج</a></div></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="loginformheader">';
    header_login_form();
    echo '<div id="reg-login"><a href="'.site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register').'">تسجيل</a><span>|</span><a style="cursor: pointer;" id="logina">دخول</a><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></div></div>';
}
?>
```